# Maven 3 copy-dependencies giving unexpected results

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

We have a project that has worked fine in Maven 2 but in Maven 3 we are having issues with copy-dependencies when it's configured as an execution inside the project pom.

```
<execution>
    <id>copy-plugin-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <excludeTypes>war,warpath</excludeTypes>
        <excludeGroupIds>org.mortbay.jetty</excludeGroupIds>
        <outputDirectory>${dir.server}/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

When run with mvn package, we are missing some dependencies from our build. However, running the equivalent from the command line:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DexcludeTypes=war,warpath -DexcludeGroupIds=org.mortbay.jetty -DoutputDirectory=${dir.server}/lib
```

We get the same dependencies we get when running it with Maven 2.

If I add execution configuration for dependency:tree I see all the dependencies printed out.

What has changed in Maven 3 to cause this?

Comment: Have you configured maven-dependency-plugin with version in your build?

Comment: Yes I have. It was originally the 2.1 release but I changed it to use the latest version (2.5.1) and had the same results.

Comment: Since the goal runs correctly by itself on the command line, it's likely something else is manipulating the `${dir.server}\lib` directory.  Check your pom (and any parent poms) to see how they are configured and what they might be doing to the lib directory.  Also, dependency resolution *did* [change between mvn3 and mvn2](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution), but that doesn't fully explain this problem.